# Specify where and how edge connects to child (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, edge

I have the following tikz tree:

[image]

I'd like to change where the edge meets the child to where I placed the red dotes. Also, I'd like to have bend edges. I've tried [bend left] but it didn't change anything (no error message either).

My code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow = right,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3em,level distance=10em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=5em, level distance=10em},
edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=blue!40!black!60},
punkt/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,thick,
    draw=blue!40!black!60, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=black!20!white,text centered,text width=8em, minimum height = 2em}]]
\node[punkt] {\textbf{Question}}
child { 
    node[punkt] {\scriptsize Question} 
    child {
        node[punkt] {\scriptsize Repetition}
    }
    edge from parent
    node[sloped,above, pos=.5] {{\scriptsize 10\%}}
}
child { 
    node[punkt] {\scriptsize Rejection} 
    child {
        node[punkt] {\scriptsize Agreement}
    }
    edge from parent
    node[sloped,above, pos=.5] {{\scriptsize 10\%}}
}
child { 
    node[punkt] {\scriptsize Pass} 
    child {
        node[punkt] {\scriptsize Acceptance}
    }
    edge from parent
    node[sloped,above, pos=.5] {{\scriptsize 10\%}}
}
child { 
    node[punkt] {\scriptsize Incorrect Answer} 
    child {node[punkt] 
        {\scriptsize Correction by Tutor}
    }
    edge from parent
    node[sloped,above, pos=.5] {{\scriptsize 10\%}}
}
child { 
    node[punkt] {\scriptsize Correct Answer} 
    child {
        node[punkt] {\scriptsize Thanks/Correct}
    }
    edge from parent
    node[sloped,above, pos=.5] {{\scriptsize 60\%}}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm thankful for any ideas you might have =)

Comment: we seem to be missing some code here. Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use options

```
child anchor=west,
edge from parent macro=\myedgefromparent,
```

with

```
\def\myedgefromparent#1#2{
  [style=edge from parent,#1]
  (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) to #2 (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
}
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow = right,
  child anchor=west,
  edge from parent macro=\myedgefromparent,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3em},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=5em},
  level distance=11em,
  edge from parent/.style={thick,draw=blue!40!black!60},
  punkt/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,thick,
      draw=blue!40!black!60, align=center,
      top color=white, bottom color=black!20!white,text centered,text width=8em, minimum height = 2em},
  every child node/.append style={punkt,font=\scriptsize},
  edge from parent/.append style={nodes={font=\scriptsize,above,sloped}}
]
\def\myedgefromparent#1#2{
  [style=edge from parent,#1]
  (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) to #2 (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
}
\node[punkt,font=\bfseries] {Question}
child { 
    node {Question} 
    child {
        node {Repetition}
    }
    edge from parent[bend right]
    node {10\%}
}
child { 
    node {Rejection} 
    child {
        node {Agreement}
    }
    edge from parent[bend right]
    node {10\%}
}
child { 
    node {Pass} 
    child {
        node {Acceptance}
    }
    edge from parent
    node {10\%}
}
child { 
    node {Incorrect Answer} 
    child {node[punkt] 
        {Correction by Tutor}
    }
    edge from parent[bend left]
    node {10\%}
}
child { 
    node {Correct Answer} 
    child {
        node {Thanks/Correct}
    }
    edge from parent[bend left]
    node {60\%}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Forest solution which automatically calculates angles for the edges based on the total number of children and the node's position in the sequence of children.

One major selling point of Forest is that the specification of the tree itself is very concise, once the tree's preamble is configured. If you need the same style of tree several times, you can pull the custom settings out of the preamble and reduce the preamble to a word or two using Forest styles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  punkt/.style = {rounded corners, thick, draw=blue!40!black!60, text centered, top color=white, bottom color=black!20!white, text width=8em, minimum height=2em},
  for tree={%
    grow=0,
    punkt,
    child anchor=parent,
  },
  where level=0{%
    font=\bfseries,
    l sep*=2,
    for children={%
      if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{}{%
        edge path/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) [out=#1, in=180] to \forestoption{edge label} (.child anchor);}{90-(180*(n_children("!u")+1-n())/(n_children("!u")+1))},
      },
    },
  }{%
    font=\scriptsize,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for tree={%
      if edge label={}{}{%
        edge label/.wrap value={node [sloped, midway, above, font=\scriptsize] {#1\%}},
      }
    }
  },
  [Question
    [Question, edge label=10
      [Repetition
      ]
    ]
    [Rejection, edge label=10
      [Agreement
      ]
    ]
    [Pass, edge label=10
      [Acceptance
      ]
    ]
    [Incorrect Answer, edge label=10
      [Correction by Tutor
      ]
    ]
    [Correct Answer, edge label=60
      [Thanks/Correct
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version]

You could use `bend left` and `bend right` but it seemed easier to go with `out` angles for purposes of automating things.