# Tikz: Problem with "sloped" in cyclic tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node

I am trying to get sloped text on an edge in a tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sloped,
    minimum size=6mm,
    align=flush center,
    concept/.style={
        draw=#1!80!black,
        very thick,
        fill=#1!25,
        rounded corners
    },
    concept/.default=white,
    description/.style={
        font=\footnotesize,
        draw,
        dashed
    },
]
\node [concept=black] {EQUITY\\MARKETS} [
    grow cyclic,
    sibling angle=120,
    level distance=5em
]
child {
    child {
        node [concept={red}] {Private} [sibling angle=90]
        child {node [description]   {Not listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
        child {
            node [concept={orange}] {Private\\Equity Fund}
            child{ node [description={above}] {Organization} }
            child { [level distance=3em, sibling angle=60]
                child{ [sibling angle=60, level distance=5em]
                    child {node {Venture\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Growth\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Leverage\\Buyout} }
                }
                edge from parent
                node [midway, sloped] {Strategies} 
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node [concept={blue}] {Public}
        child {node [description] {Listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
    }
    edge from parent
    node [midway,sloped] {Types} 
}
child { node[description={right}] {Ownership\\of Entity} }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have "Types" and "Strategies" sloped over the edges.

I have tried to use the sloped option, but that is not changing anything.

I am using Overleaf, if that matters.

And, if there is any other way to improve the code, I would appreciate your suggestions. I am just starting now and not very good with Ti*k*Z.
[image: Here is my output]

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, Sorry, edited accordingly.

Comment: Your edited code gives an error. Please correct it.

Comment: @cfr Sorry fort that, and thanks for pointing out. There was a typo. I have fixed it now, and confirm that the edited code gives the image I have uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I don't know why it doesn't work :(. (I mean why the things aren't `sloped`.)

Comment: @cfr I checked code in this question: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316703/specify-where-and-how-edge-connects-to-child-tikz). The only difference I can think of is that my tree grows cyclic. Bdw, do you think I should strip some of the formatting code? Would that make it easier for others to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question! And your suspicion that this is triggered by `grow cyclic` is right to the point. The problem is that `grow cyclic` installs its own transformations. So these nodes *are* sloped, but relative to a rotated coordinate system, so they end up not being sloped. This can be seen from the lines

```
\tikzset{grow cyclic/.style={growth function=\tikz@grow@circle}}%
```

and

```
\def\tikz@grow@circle{%
  \pgftransformrotate{%
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(-.5-.5*\tikznumberofchildren+\tikznumberofcurrentchild)}%
  \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
}%
```

in `tikzlibrarytrees.code.tex`. So one way to avoid this is to

1. define your own `edge from parent macro` in which
2. you locally reset these transformations.

Code and result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,scopes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    minimum size=6mm,
    align=flush center,
    concept/.style={
        draw=#1!80!black,
        very thick,
        fill=#1!25,
        rounded corners
    },
    concept/.default=white,
    description/.style={
        font=\footnotesize,
        draw,
        dashed
    },
    edge from parent macro=\mymacro
]
\def\mymacro#1#2{[style=edge from parent, #1]
{[/utils/exec=\pgftransformreset](\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) -- #2
(\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)} }
\node [concept=black] {EQUITY\\MARKETS} [
    grow cyclic,
    sibling angle=120,
    level distance=5em
]
child {
    child {
        node [concept={red}] {Private} [sibling angle=90]
        child {node [description]   {Not listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
        child {
            node [concept={orange}] {Private\\Equity Fund}
            child{ node [description={above}] {Organization} }
            child { [level distance=3em, sibling angle=60]
                child{ [sibling angle=60, level distance=5em]
                    child {node {Venture\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Growth\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Leverage\\Buyout} }
                }
                edge from parent
                node [pos=1.2,sloped,above] {Strategies} 
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node [concept={blue}] {Public}
        child {node [description] {Listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
    }
    edge from parent
    node [pos=0.6,sloped,above] {Types} 
}
child { node[description={right}] {Ownership\\of Entity} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Henri Menke shared with me a much simpler and more elegant way to accomplish this. Just add `edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}`. Full credit goes to Henri Menke.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    minimum size=6mm,
    align=flush center,
    concept/.style={
        draw=#1!80!black,
        very thick,
        fill=#1!25,
        rounded corners
    },
    concept/.default=white,
    description/.style={
        font=\footnotesize,
        draw,
        dashed
    },
    edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}
]
\node [concept=black] {EQUITY\\MARKETS} [
    grow cyclic,
    sibling angle=120,
    level distance=5em
]
child {
    child {
        node [concept={red}] {Private} [sibling angle=90]
        child {node [description]   {Not listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
        child {
            node [concept={orange}] {Private\\Equity Fund}
            child{ node [description={above}] {Organization} }
            child { [level distance=3em, sibling angle=60]
                child{ [sibling angle=60, level distance=5em]
                    child {node {Venture\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Growth\\Capital} }
                    child {node {Leverage\\Buyout} }
                }
                edge from parent
                node [pos=1.2,sloped,above] {Strategies} 
            }
        }
    }
    child {
        node [concept={blue}] {Public}
        child {node [description] {Listed on\\Stock Exchange} }
    }
    edge from parent
    node [pos=0.6,sloped,above] {Types} 
}
child { node[description={right}] {Ownership\\of Entity} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This leads to the same result, and so does patching `grow cyclic` with

```
 \tikzset{grow cyclic/.append style={edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution works beautifully. I still have a question, though, you said, >these nodes are sloped, but relative to a rotated coordinate system, so they end up not being sloped. If that were the case, wouldn't they appear sloped without the `sloped` option? And also, where can I read more about these macros and how to reconfigure them? Again, thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am using `scopes` to make the reset local.

Comment: @AmatyaRakshasaKathyayan What I want to say is that in the rotated coordinate system the edge that connects parent with child has slope 0, so they are "sloped". The edge from parent macro is described on p. 336 pf pgfmanual v3.1.4. The core level functions `\pgftransformrotate`, `\pgftransformreset` and so on are part of the pgfmanual, too, but they are described in a way that suggests that the standard user is not supposed to mess with them. ;-) BTW, I am almost inclined to suggest to report this issue at github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you think its worth it, I can try to report this issue.

Comment: @AmatyaRakshasaKathyayan I have no strong opinion, mainly wanted to mention the fact that there is a place to report such issues.

Comment: @AmatyaRakshasaKathyayan I think it is worth reporting. Either `sloped` should work or the documentation should mention it doesn't, since the examples clearly show other options (e.g. `left` etc.) working. This means an end-user is fully entitled to be unpleasantly surprised when `sloped` doesn't.

Comment: Will go ahead and report the issue. Schrödinger'scat, thank very much you for your help. @cfr Thank you for looking into the problem, and the suggesting to report.

Comment: No need to muck around with `edge from parent macro`.  Just do [`edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}`](https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/3c909b7792ad5e18f175d28a49adf58c7b9ad07e)

Comment: The advantage of `edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}` is that this can be easily overridden by the user as well.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! Yes, this is definitely simpler. (I was perhaps too worried to keep the reset local, so I wanted to put it in a scope. But you are right, what you are suggesting should be safe.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I stuffed it into `grow cyclic`, so it is as local as `grow cyclic`, so in your user code you'd do `grow cyclic/.append style={edge from parent/.append style={reset cm}}` at global scope after loading the `trees` library.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's clever, yes.